# WaitForSingleObject returns wait failed due to invalid handle

Tags: mfc

I am trying to use a `CEvent` to make my thread wait until the message queue is ready as per [MSDN's advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that my `PostThreadMessage` function will work correctly.

```
BOOL MFC_Thread::InitInstance(){
BOOL worked=CWinThread::InitInstance();
MSG msg;
BOOL result=PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);
    fingerveinControllerThreadReady->SetEvent();//Breakpoint 1
    return TRUE;
}

void init(){
    controllerThreadReady=new CEvent(FALSE, FALSE);
CWinThread* thread=AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(MFC_Thread));
controllerThread=thread->m_nThreadID;
WaitForSingleObject(controllerThreadReady, INFINITE);
    DoSomething();//Breakpoint 2
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the `WaitForSingleObject` isn't doing its job. Sometimes Breakpoint 1 is hit first, sometimes Breakpoint 2. When Breakpoint 2 is hit first, I receive `WAIT_FAILED` with the cause `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might be because you're passing the `CEvent` object instead of its handle.

Try this:

`WaitForSingleObject(controllerThreadReady.m_hObject, INFINITE);`

Comment: I am using the [operator HANDLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f5zcch25%28v=VS.80%29.aspx): doesn't this get the handle of the operator?

Comment: Okay, I tried your advice and it seems to work now. Do you know what the operator is for then?

Comment: You weren't using operator HANDLE: you were calling WaitForSingleObject with a CEvent* as the first argument. Since HANDLE is a typedef for a void* this is accepted, and the call was trying to interpret the CEvent* as a handle. To use the operator would require something like WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE)*controllerThreadReady,...)